# Can I use editing credits in my grad school app for english program? If so, how?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions

In undergrad I was lead student editor for two poetry anthologies, one of which I received a grant for. I'm now applying to an MA English program and would love to include this information but I'm not sure how. On the application, it has a spot for publications etc, but then just says to upload a file. I don't have the original manuscripts or anything, I just have the physical books and an amazon link. I also don't have any of the correspondence from my undergrad about the grant. How should I approach including this information? Do editing credits count as publications?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an appropriate thing to add to your CV and such is normally required for grad school admissions.

No, editing is a "publication" per se, but it is an academic activity. "Publications etc." probably means a CV, a listing of you past academic accomplishments and publications.